# Include GIT installation in a Java app

Tags: java, git, jar

I have a Java app that uses GIT.

I want to install GIT seamlessly on the user's computer - mac, win & linux - instead of asking them to install it on their own...

How can I include the GIT installation inside a Java app?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need GIT on `client` machine ?

Comment: Most installers allow you to bring a file system.  That file system can contain a git distribution.  I'd go for jgit though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [JGit](http://eclipse.org/jgit/) as a standalone Java implementation of git, rather than using the native implementation. This will make it much easier to bundle with your Java application, as well as allowing for easier interoperability with Java. JGit is specifically designed to be embeddable in Java applications.

Comment: JGit is pure Java library without any native code to interop.